# How to create a Self extracting installer for windows from unix

Tags: unix, sfx

From Windows, using the `Iexpress` tool, I could create a Self extracting installer, containing an .NET Application and an XML file. On invoking the output file, I could successfully execute the .NET application.

But, I want to do this from UNIX. I am new to UNIX and I am looking for an open source tool or step by step procedure to compress the .NET exe and XML file as a Windows executable, which on execution from a Windows machine, should directly execute the .NET executable.

I tried with `unzipsfx-552_win32/unzipsfx.exe`, but i could not successfully complete it.

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: I did it with 7 Zip archive, 
step 1: compress the required files.
/usr/local/bin/7za a -t7z my7zfile.7z file1 file2 file3 ...

step 2: create a config file(config.txt) in the same folder, like below given contents.

;!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title="Your application title"
RunProgram="Exe name with extension that needs to be called post extraction"
;!@InstallEnd@!

Step 3: create the final exe
along with the 7za rpm you will get 7zS.sfx file
with that i could create an exe, which self extarcts and calls the application with in it.

cat 7zS.sfx config.txt my7zfile.7z > Selfextract.exe